# what kind of method or operation will use a little more CPU relatively in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

"a lot of" may be too exaggerating.

what kind of method or operation will use a little more CPU relatively in Objective-C

I just know that method like "+alloc" will take a little more CPU relatively,right?

what about others ?

what about [UIImage imageNamed:@"XX.png"]，addSubView，removeFromSuperView

I always feel that when a method need to read files,it will take a litte more time relatively.

Comment: any method (that you wrote) can use a lot of CPU. You need to learn how to profile your application.

Comment: not sure this is a very productive question.  It's hard to quantify "alot" let alone list methods.

Comment: What you should be concerned about is the way in which you design and implement your program. The best way to speed up your program is to improve the algorithms that control it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just know that method like "+alloc" will take a lot of cpu
>   resources,right?

Nope;  that won't.

`+alloc` is nothing more than a `malloc()` with a bit of byte zeroing.  Relatively cheap unless you call it about a zillion times.  Under ARC, it can be slightly more expensive, depending on use... but, still, nowhere near "a lot of CPU resources".

What, really, area you asking about?